# How do you set a not null constraint in activerecord for ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a migration that looks like this:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string  :title 
      t.string  :content
      t.string  :author
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

How do I set title to be NOT NULL?  If it were an SQL query, I would do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "posts" 
    ("id" serial primary key, 
     "title" character varying(255) NOT NULL, 
     "content" character varying(255), 
     "author" character varying(255), 
     "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, 
     "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL)
```

So how do I translate that query into ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 20):

To set a non-null constraint at the database level, add `null: false` to the ActiveRecord migration. For example,

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string  :title,   null: false
      t.string  :content, null: false
      t.string  :author,  null: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

You should also (or can alternatively) add a presence validator to your model, which operates at the Rails level and provides informative error messages to your end-users:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :content, :author, presence: true
end
```

see the [Rails Guides on presence validation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `t.string :title` line to

```
t.string  :title, null: false
```